# How to set mmdb_dir in Zeek/Bro

Tags: bro, zeek

I try to use GeoIp functionality in Bro/Zeek.

From the official [Zeek Documentation](https://docs.zeek.org/en/current/frameworks/geoip.html#geolocation):

> If you see an error message similar to “Failed to open GeoIP location database”, then you may need to either rename or move your GeoIP location database file. If the mmdb_dir value is set to a directory pathname (it is not set by default), then Zeek looks for location database files in that directory.

Ok, `mmdb_dir` is not set:

```
/pcap # zeek -e "print mmdb_dir;"

/pcap #
```

I downloaded the mmdb files from Maxmind and copied them into the pcap folder.
I do not want to add them into the default path, but configure `mmdb_dir` permanently. Is this possible and how can this be done?

---

Extra infos: I am running version 3.0.1 in a docker container started with with the following commands:

```
# on host system
Host:~$ docker run --rm -it \
                 -v `pwd`/pcap:/pcap \
                 -v `pwd`/local.zeek:/usr/local/zeek/share/zeek/site/local.zeek \
                 --entrypoint /bin/sh \
                 blacktop/zeek

# now in docker container
/pcap # zeek --version
zeek version 3.0.1
/pcap # zeek -e "print lookup_location(8.8.8.8);"
error in <command line>, line 1: Failed to open GeoIP location database (lookup_location(8.8.8.8))
[country_code=<uninitialized>, region=<uninitialized>, city=<uninitialized>, latitude=<uninitialized>, longitude=<uninitialized>]
fatal error in <command line>, line 3: errors occurred while initializing
```

Link to the container description on GitHub: https://github.com/blacktop/docker-zeek.

When copying/mounting the `*.mmdb` files to `/usr/local/share/GeoIP` it works fine.

---

Update:
I added the redef (thx to [Christian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61377719/2317497)) `/usr/local/zeek/share/zeek/site/local.zeek`:

```
##! Local site policy. Customize as appropriate.
##!
##! This file will not be overwritten when upgrading or reinstalling!

# This script logs which scripts were loaded during each run.
@load misc/loaded-scripts

# Apply the default tuning scripts for common tuning settings.
@load tuning/defaults

# Estimate and log capture loss.
@load misc/capture-loss

# Enable logging of memory, packet and lag statistics.
@load misc/stats

# Load the scan detection script.  It's disabled by default because
# it often causes performance issues.
#@load misc/scan

# Detect traceroute being run on the network. This could possibly cause
# performance trouble when there are a lot of traceroutes on your network.
# Enable cautiously.
#@load misc/detect-traceroute

# Generate notices when vulnerable versions of software are discovered.
# The default is to only monitor software found in the address space defined
# as "local".  Refer to the software framework's documentation for more
# information.
@load frameworks/software/vulnerable

# Detect software changing (e.g. attacker installing hacked SSHD).
@load frameworks/software/version-changes

# This adds signatures to detect cleartext forward and reverse windows shells.
@load-sigs frameworks/signatures/detect-windows-shells

# Load all of the scripts that detect software in various protocols.
@load protocols/ftp/software
@load protocols/smtp/software
@load protocols/ssh/software
@load protocols/http/software
# The detect-webapps script could possibly cause performance trouble when
# running on live traffic.  Enable it cautiously.
#@load protocols/http/detect-webapps

# This script detects DNS results pointing toward your Site::local_nets
# where the name is not part of your local DNS zone and is being hosted
# externally.  Requires that the Site::local_zones variable is defined.
@load protocols/dns/detect-external-names

# Script to detect various activity in FTP sessions.
@load protocols/ftp/detect

# Scripts that do asset tracking.
@load protocols/conn/known-hosts
@load protocols/conn/known-services
@load protocols/ssl/known-certs

# This script enables SSL/TLS certificate validation.
@load protocols/ssl/validate-certs

# This script prevents the logging of SSL CA certificates in x509.log
@load protocols/ssl/log-hostcerts-only

# Uncomment the following line to check each SSL certificate hash against the ICSI
# certificate notary service; see http://notary.icsi.berkeley.edu .
# @load protocols/ssl/notary

# If you have GeoIP support built in, do some geographic detections and
# logging for SSH traffic.
@load protocols/ssh/geo-data
# Detect hosts doing SSH bruteforce attacks.
@load protocols/ssh/detect-bruteforcing
# Detect logins using "interesting" hostnames.
@load protocols/ssh/interesting-hostnames

# Detect SQL injection attacks.
@load protocols/http/detect-sqli

#### Network File Handling ####

# Enable MD5 and SHA1 hashing for all files.
@load frameworks/files/hash-all-files

# Detect SHA1 sums in Team Cymru's Malware Hash Registry.
@load frameworks/files/detect-MHR

# Extend email alerting to include hostnames
@load policy/frameworks/notice/extend-email/hostnames

# Uncomment the following line to enable detection of the heartbleed attack. Enabling
# this might impact performance a bit.
# @load policy/protocols/ssl/heartbleed

# Uncomment the following line to enable logging of connection VLANs. Enabling
# this adds two VLAN fields to the conn.log file.
# @load policy/protocols/conn/vlan-logging

# Uncomment the following line to enable logging of link-layer addresses. Enabling
# this adds the link-layer address for each connection endpoint to the conn.log file.
# @load policy/protocols/conn/mac-logging

# I added this line:
redef mmdb_dir = "/pcap";
```

But the database is still not loading, unless I tell `zeek` to use the `local` config ([RTFM](https://docs.zeek.org/en/current/quickstart/#local-site-customization)).

```
/pcap # zeek -e "print lookup_location(8.8.8.8);" local "Site::local_nets += { 192.168.0.0/24 }"
[country_code=US, region=<uninitialized>, city=<uninitialized>, latitude=37.751, longitude=-97.822]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is defined (with an empty string value) as a redef'able constant in the `init-bare.zeek` file that comes with the distribution. So just say

```
redef mmdb_dir = "/pcap";
```

(or whatever is the final destination) in your `local.zeek` file, and you should be all set.